# Can we abolish the Analytical badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

There's a [badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/77/analytical) called 'Analytical' whose description reads:

> Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)

Since this badge is **retired** and nobody has got it so far, that means nobody is *ever* going to get it. Is there any point in having this badge on the badge page? Is it possible for it to be removed?

Comment: Is it worthwhile to un-retire the FAQ and make it sensible, instead?

Comment: FAQ was replaced with the Help Center, so in a sense, it still does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Probably not.

If we were to do this, it would be for all sites on the network that don't already have someone who has earned the badge. But [that request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185009/should-unearnable-badges-been-shown-under-unearned) has been declined.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the [Precognitive](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/precognitive) and [Beta](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) badges, there are users (on other sites) that already have the Analytical badge. Hence, it can't be removed entirely.

Hiding the badge only on sites where it hasn't been awarded isn't really worth it, and the developers have more significant things to be worrying about.